# How to build Google Assistant into Raspberry Pi?

Tags: actions-on-google

Google said that with their SDK we could build the Assistant into a wide range of products, for example the Raspberry Pi.

Now it's launched and I can't see that function, did I miss something?

Comment: [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/) just launched. [Here is the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/), how to set up on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look out for the Embedded Google Assistant SDK which will allow you to add the Google Assistant to a Raspberry Pi. This was not part of today's launch.

Comment: Thanks, when might we expect the SDK?

Comment: As far as I know, we have no information about that yet.